# Better algorithm for finding solutions to "a + b = c + d"

Tags: algorithm

So lets abcd is a number between 1000 and 9999 and a,b,c,d are it's digits.
So find the number, where a+b=c+d. There is one solution down with four loops, but i need 
a solution with three loops.

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d <= 9; d++)
            {
                if ((a + b) == (c + d))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: After you have `a`, `b`, and `c`, what must `d` be? Once you have it, do you then still need to loop over it?

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that way , but i haven't put my if condition right .

Answer (score 5):

If someone asked you to solve the `x + 1 == 2` equation, would you actually attempt to loop over all possible values of `x` to see which one fits? I hope not. You will probably figure out that the equation permits an immediate direct analytical solution `x = 2 - 1 = 1`.

The same logic applies to your case. Once you know `a`, `b` and `c`, your `a + b == c + d` equation permits a direct solution for `d`: `d = a + b - c`. There's no need to iterate over `d` just like there's no need to iterate over `x` in `x + 1 == 2`.

Comment: +1. Note: picking values for a, b, and c; then solving for d, still requires you to check that the value computed is a valid value for d. Example: a=1, b=9, c=0. d=10 which would not be a valid combination.

Comment: There's also probably no need to iterate over c. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

The first 3 loops establish values for a, b, and c. Knowing this and your equation just compute what d needs to be in order for your equation to hold true. Then check that the number computed for d is valid.

```
 for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
 {
    for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
    {
       for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
       {
          d = a + b - c;
          if (d <= 9 && d >= 0) 
          {
             Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
          }
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have a special case of 4SUM that can be solved via one of the ways to quadratically solve [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm), making it O(N^2). Although it requires some use of data structures.

The first thing to note is since you are looking for A + B = C + D, What you really want to do is find a list of pairs of numbers that add up to some number S.

You can simply this by having a map/dict where the key is the sum and it maps to an list of pairs that equal that sum. The result is:

```
S = [(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),...] for a number of values of S
```

Which is equivalent to saying:

```
a + b = c + d = e + f = ... = S for a number of values of S
```

You then simply go through each sum and remove the ones where there is only a single element in the list.

I'm thinking you can then break go through the combinations of pairs obtaining things like a + b = c + d and c + d = e + f, at a cost of an additional O(N^2) as long as there are no duplicates due to limits on how many ways you can obtain a sum. Although, I might be wrong and it takes O(N^3) to list the solution in that form.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = Enumerable.Range(1000, 9000);
            var list = from y in number
                       let a = y / 1000
                       let b = (y - 1000 * a) / 100
                       let c = (y - 1000 * a - 100 * b) / 10
                       let d = (y - 1000 * a - 100 * b - 10 * c)
                       where a + b == c + d
                       select y;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1;
Set<String> s=new TreeSet();
for( int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
   s1=null;
    s1=""+i;
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
       String tempj=s1;
        s1=s1+j;
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            String tempk=s1;
        s1=s1+k;
        int temp=i+j-k;
        s1=s1+temp;
        if(temp<10)
        s.add(s1);
        s1=tempk;
        }
      s1=tempj;  
    }

}

for(String i:s )
System.out.println(i+);
```

----------------------------------------------------------------EDIT 1------------------

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
  String happyNumber;
 Set<String> numberSet=new TreeSet();
 for( int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
    happyNumber=null;           //Every 1st loop will give a new number so old one has to be deleted
    happyNumber=""+i;           //Adding the number in 1st place (place value will be i*10000)
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)       //Loop for putting nmber in 1000th place
        {
            String tempj=happyNumber;    //taking happyNumber( only one digit fixed till now) into a temp variable to permutate on other places
            happyNumber=happyNumber+j;   //Attaching another number after this we have (AB)
            for(int k=0;k<10;k++)        //permutating with value of c and calculating d    
                {
                    String tempk=happyNumber; 
                    happyNumber=happyNumber+k;  //Attaching variable for 3rd place (c)
                    int temp=i+j-k;             //calculating value of d
                    if(temp<10)                 //checking whether we have right value for d 
                        {
                        happyNumber=happyNumber+temp;
                        numberSet.add(happyNumber);
                        }
                    happyNumber=tempk;          //bringing number back to its previous state for more combination
                }
                happyNumber=tempj;              //bringing number back to its previous state for more combination
        }

    }

    for(String i:numberSet )
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use reasonable variable names and explain your code?

Comment: @Robert  : here you go...(Edit 1)

Comment: Hm, if you think that is better, let's just say you better not apply for a job in my company :-)

Comment: @Robert, It is better than 4 loops as asked in the question, instead of adding into list I can print it loop itself, but I just did in case  if this set is used for any other operation.I am not writing for a job interview, neither I am writing a code golf......